# Make MySQLi conenction variable available inside functions too

Tags: php, mysqli

A PHP page say, **common.php** contains the line, with some other PHP variables and code.

```
$mysqli=new MySQLi("localhost", "username", "password");
```

So in the other pages, I simple include this common.php, using `require_once("common.php")` and use the `$mysqli` variable for all database related operations. Everything works fine. In a random situation, I need to create a function inside a PHP page such as,

```
function checking($some_data)
{
  // Using $mysqli check $some_data with database here and return 0 or 1 based on database operations
  // Here it says $mysqli is not defined.
}

$somevariable=$mysqli->prepare($query); // This is outside the function and works fine
$result=checking($some_data); // This does not work and says $mysqli not defined.
```

I tried adding `global $mysqli` inside the function. But if I do that, MySQLi connection is not available for that. Defining `$mysqli` inside each and every function with connection parameters, sound insane. What may be the simple solution?

Comment: Either use a parameter inside the function to pass `$mysqli` along or add `global $mysqli;` to grab it from the global scope. If you're opening the connection inside another function you need to add that line to the function too so `$mysqli` gets created in the global scope.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `global $mysqli` inside the function will work pretty in this case. If it does not work, you are doing a mistake somewhere in your function or in the query(may be).

```
function function_name_here($arguement_variable_here)
{
  global $mysqli;
  $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

And make sure, you include the dependency file - *common.php* before the function definition. If the include/require is done below the function(s) definition, probably that may not work in some cases.